# Django Accepting AM/PM As Form Input

Tags: python, django, forms, datetime

I am trying to figure out how to accept am/pm as a time format in Django using a DateTime field, but I am having some trouble. I have tried setting it like this in my forms.py file

```
pickup_date_time_from = DateTimeField(input_formats=["%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"])
```

with the following data:

```
12/31/2017 02:40 pm
```

However, I get a validation error when submitting the form:

```
(Hidden field pickup_date_time_from) Enter a valid date/time.
```

I have also tried setting a global variable in settings.py as the documentation states:

```
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p']
```

What does work is if I submit the data without the am/pm, but the output is

```
2017-12-31 02:40:00+00:00
```

Any other options?

Comment: Is localization turned on for you project? That'd be ` USE_L10N = True` in your settings file. If not, does turning it on solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, localization is set to True

Comment: You can't do this with the built-in parser - see the [note here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/formatting/#locale-aware-input-in-forms).

Comment: @solarissmoke I undated my code to:             pickup_date_time_from = DateTimeField(input_formats=["%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"],localize=True)
    but, I still get the invalid data/time error.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. As per the note I link to above, Django cannot parse datetimes containing `%p`.

Answer (score 1):

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS doesn't work for formats containg **%p**.
Neither do `input_formats` kwarg.

As a quick work around, you can alter the `input_formats` attribute of `DateTimeField` in the `Form`'s `__init__` method.
For example:

```
class DateTimeForm(forms.Form):
    CUSTOM_FORMAT = '%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p'

    date_input = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.CUSTOM_FORMAT not in self.fields['date_input'].input_formats:
            self.fields['date_input'].input_formats.append(self.CUSTOM_FORMAT)
```

Django documentation **does** say that %p cannot be used in parsing date fields.

But if you go through [the source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/forms/fields/#DateTimeField), the to_python method of DateTimeField doesn't really enforce anything like that.