# Django Form Doesn't Accept DateTime From DateTimePicker

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm working on a todo web app and has a user enter an events datetime with a custom bootstrap datetimepicker from [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/). I have the custom widgets on a form formatted to MM/DD/YY hh:mm A. However, Django doesn't accept the form. A similar question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046121/django-accepting-am-pm-as-form-input/52479049), but instead of overriding the default DateTimeInput, I would like the form to display in a certain format but be stored in a database in the default format. I'm thinking of using widget tweaks to customize the picker but I don't know how to store it in default formats. What would be the best way to do this?

Forms.py

```
from bootstrap_modal_forms.forms import BSModalForm
from .widgets import BootstrapDateTimePickerInput
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DateTimePickerInput
from .models import ToDoItem

class NewEventForm(BSModalForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ToDoItem
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'remind_time']
        widgets = {
            'start_time': DateTimePickerInput(
                options={"format": "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"}
            ), 
            'end_time': DateTimePickerInput(
                options={"format": "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"}
            ),
            'remind_time': DateTimePickerInput(
                options={"format": "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"}
            ),
        }
```

Event form:

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load static %}
{% bootstrap_css %}   
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Custom Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/main.css' %}">

    <!-- Moment.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-VBLiveTKyUZMEzJd6z2mhfxIqz3ZATCuVMawPZGzIfA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    {{ form.media }} 
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action=""> 
    {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">New Event</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body"> 
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                    {% bootstrap_form form %}
            </fieldset> 
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="submit-btn btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the frontend using at least 3 well-known JS date/time manipulators and the native stack. And you can do it in the backend, using django's tools, the python datetime library, a library called [dateparse](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [dateparser](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/), python [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) etc etc.

It's a commonly solved problem (for school papers for example) :)

But the one thing that's going to help you is to know that form fields have a method called [`to_python()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning): you can subclass the [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield) and override the method.

You don't have to take care of the way back, but for completeness if you wanted to, it would be [`Widget.format_value()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.format_value).

The best format to use in the backend (or actually everywhere where humans don't have to look at it) is [Iso8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but does it matter if I use models.DateTimeField or forms.DateTimeField? I'm quite new to Django and I don't know the difference. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, I would subclass DateTimeField for the backend date storage and use the js to display the date?

Comment: The model datetime field is close to the database layer. The form is sent to the form layer, where you have forms.DateTimeField and so it makes more sense to do any transformations there. The database version of that field, deals with translations from and to the database. And yes, you'd display using that custom widget and then "intercept" the input in the form field.

Comment: If I use the forms.DateTimeField, where would I tell the DateTimePicker to sublass from my overridden DateTimeField instead of the regular Django one? Would I have to override the custom widget too?